# How to restore docker postgres container?

Tags: docker, database-restore

I am totally newbie with docker. Unfortunately, I nave made a change - I set a vew environment variable from GUI and it astonishingly caused container re-creation! All postgreSQL DBs have been lost.
So, two questions:
Why did it happen?
is there a way to rollback? (There were no backups or something else).

Comment: please post your configuration to help us understand your problem

Answer (score 0):

There are a fairly broad set of changes that require deleting and recreating containers.  As you've discovered, this includes changing environment variables; it also includes published ports, host-mapped directories, and changing the image underneath the container.  In turn, the image will change if there's ever any sort of security update, software patch release, or just a new application build.

In short: **deleting Docker containers is very common and you need to make sure the data gets preserved**.

The standard way to do this is is to mount some additional storage into the container.  Docker provides a [named volume](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) system, but the named volumes can be opaque and hard to manage; it's often easier to [bind mount](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/) a host directory.  (N.B.: the linked documentation advocates for named volumes, IME host directories are easier to inspect and manage with readily-available non-Docker tools.)  You need to look at each image's documentation to know where to attach the storage, but for the standard [postgres](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/) image it is in `/var/lib/postgresql/data` (see "Where To Store Data" at the end of the linked page).  In plain Docker you could run

```sh
docker run \
  -d \
  -p 5432:5432 \
  -v ./postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data \
  postgres:11
```

but there's presumably a setting for that in your GUI tool.

Your previous data is probably lost.  Docker doesn't keep snapshots of containers, and deleting a container actually deletes it and its underlying data.  You still need to do things like take backups of your data in case Docker or some other part of your system fails.